# Cannot execute transaction because gas fees are set to 0

Tags: gnosis-safe

We're trying to execute transaction with nonce 2 here: https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0x0Dd0Dd95625227A9DEa5D9C822aA15C14400901B/transactions/queue

Data from GS:

```
Operation:
1 (delegate)
safeTxGas:
0
baseGas:
0
gasPrice:
0
gasToken:
0x00000000...00000000

refundReceiver:
0x00000000...00000000

Signature 1:
65 bytes

Raw data:
2532 bytes
```

We can't change gas fees in GS and when opening Metamask, it defaults to 0, so we have to estimate it ourselves.

The transaction proposal was created using `@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client` and nothing about gas was specified there.

Questions:

1. How do we execute the transaction?
2. How do we use the Safe Service Client when proposing transactions so that gas will just be figured out?

Answer (score 0):

> We can't change gas fees in GS and when opening Metamask, it defaults to 0

It means the transaction is reverting and metamask couldn't estimate the limit. You need to simulate the transaction to find out why it is failing. Tenderly may help with it.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to how to debug that with Tenderly?